# Is there a Salesforce equivalent of Unica Optimize?

Tags: campaign, performance

I am somewhat familiar with Unica's Optimize engine. This compares different campaigns customers are eligible for to determine which one they should be placed into in order to get the optimal business outcome (rather than spamming them via multiple campaigns).

At a high level how does Salesforce address this issue? If there are multiple campaigns that a customer could become a member of, does Salesforce have some principled approach to selecting only one for that customer?

A related problem, if there are more customers eligible for a campaign than can be executed (for some budget constraint) what is Salesforce's approach to selecting the best customers to contact?

Note that I'm not a direct user of these systems, I'm interested in some high level understanding in the context of mass direct marketing campaigns.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce's Marketing Cloud includes Einstein, which is a deep learning algorithm (referred to by salesforce.com as Artificial Intelligence) to provide predictive marketing, allowing you to select leads and accounts that are more likely to respond to campaigns based on available data. There are, of course, additional costs for this feature, but can dramatically improve sales and ROI. There are also AppExchange products of varying quality and pricing for [marketing](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/category/marketing) as well. Feel free to research a few and figure out which one makes the most sense for your organization's business model.